# Refresh changes in a Asp.Net app with Docker local development

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docker

First of all let me say I'm not familiar with Asp.Net and I have a very basic knowledge of **Docker**, so maybe this question is really dumb, but I can't find a way to fix this

We're developing a project with [Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin) and I need to apply some HTML & CSS to the pages to match the new design

I have installed the project on my computer and can run it now with **Docker**, my team has shown me how to edit the templates and all that stuff

The problem I have is, to preview every change I need to rebuild all the containers with:

`docker compose up --build`

This is really slow to work with, so my question is:

Is there a way to restart the Asp.Net project inside the Docker container everytime I change something?

Comment: Look's like we have the same problem, as I have done some researches, and my knowledge with Docker, to apply the changes you have to push the new image to local or docker hub (this part doesn't matter), In this case, building the docker compose, pushes the images and then you can see the changes. *This is from personal experience* .